# How to run program in system console using Pycharm or Clion?

Tags: pycharm, clion

How to run a program directly in Windows console using either Pycharm or Clion? Every time I start a program it executes in window inside IDE, which is not what I want.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve with that?